# Java Web Application Flow

Tags: java

In an web application,how can we know the flow of execution.(All the method calls when a particular button in an webpage is clicked). I know that Stack Trace would be helpful if there is an exception.But,is there any way to find the flow by using eclipse for normal execution.

Comment: Debug the project by checking click event of button

Comment: While debuggin in eclipse , I am unable to find the complete trace. I am only able to find the trace form debug point

Comment: You want solution for exception or what? Hope you are clear about what you are asking. Put debug point in method you want to check.

Comment: Hi @Vicky Thakor, I dont want to check for exception. I want to know the complete flow. Can I know the flow without debug point?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not the kind of thing that an IDE normally provides, and it is certainly is not available as standard Eclipse functionality.

What Eclipse *does* provide is functionality like:

- Displaying exception call stacks
- Setting breakpoints and stepping in the debugger
- Call graphs / trees
- Class hierarchy graphs
- Declaration <-> Implementation <-> Reference navigation.

... which when taken together are probably a lot more manageable than a "complete control flow".

There is an Eclipse plugin called "Control Flow Graph Factory" which might be what you want, and there might be others in the Eclipse Marketplace.